# Is it still not possible to use english names for all countries even in non-english Countries in OpenStreetMaps

Tags: openstreetmap

Not sure if this helps. I am using vue-leaflet and using OpenStreetMaps('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') as tileProvider.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your [TileLayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#tilelayer) URL tile.openstreetmap.org uses local names for labels. Labels in England will be in English, labels in France will be in French and so on.

If you want to have all-English labels then use an all-English [tile server](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers). Read [map internationalization](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization) for more information. Also make sure to check the usage policy of the tile server you have chosen.

Please note that his question has [already been answered dozens of time](https://www.google.de/search?q=openstreetmap+all-english).

Comment: Can you give me an example link which I can use in leaflet? so there is no option in openStreetMaps to use only english names?

Comment: [Map internationalization](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization) has some options. https://www.thunderforest.com/maps/ has multiple styles with all-english + local labels tiles. Again, make sure to check their usage policy.